# Adding a header for tabulated-list-mode

Tags: tabulated-list-mode

Is it possible to display a header with `tabulated-list-mode`, and if so, how ?

I could not introduce a header with this code

```
(defun tlprint-alist (alist &optional outbufr keytl valtl)
  "Print an associated list via `tabulated-list-print'."

  (let*
      ( (bufr (or outbufr (get-buffer-create "*Alist2*")))
        (keytl (or keytl "Key Title"))
        (valtl (or valtl "Value Title")) )

    (with-current-buffer bufr
      (tabulated-list-mode)
      (setq buffer-read-only nil)
      (setq tabulated-list-format
             (vector (list keytl 20 t) (list valtl 20 t)))
      (setq tabulated-list-sort-key (cons keytl nil))
      (setq tabulated-list-entries
            (mapcar (lambda (dyad)
                      (list (car dyad) (cdr dyad)))
                    alist))
      (tabulated-list-init-header)
      (tabulated-list-print) )))
```

Comment: Hasn't this question already been answered, even multiple times? Maybe here (?), but certainly in help-gnu-emacs (at least 2 threads): https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2023-06/msg00160.html.

Comment: FWIW, I get the feeling that what you're really trying to do (`Y`) isn't being asked about, and instead you're asking about this and that part of some ways (`X`) that you expect will let you do `Y`. Does [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821) ring a bell here? (If not, ignore.)

Comment: There is the command `(tabulated-list-init-header)` but have not managed to find a way to show a header in the buffer.  I only get the values printed.

Comment: @Drew Have looked at the link but the example mentioned there does not word when I run the example code.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but the menu that is visible with `M-x list-buffers` uses a header-line with `tabulated-list-mode`.  Perhaps it might be helpful to see how that function works ...